# How to keep my views from being redrawn

Tags: android

I have a simple app.  And I would prefer the views stay the way they are when the orientation change.  How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Incomplete question! Define "stay the way they are"! Same size? Same position? Prevent orientation change? What is "View" for you? Like class in Android (for example TextView) or the whole layout used for activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Nunu's answer you may wish to override `onConfigurationChanged(...)` to make any essential changes to your views.

You can also lock activities to portrait or landscape in the manifest.

EDIT

To lock in portrait declare your activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yourpackage.YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: Right, I'd like to lock in portrait.  What should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the activity in the manifest file..

```
 <activity
        android:name="..." android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

And read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should check the sample application of "Multiresolution" in your android-sdk-windows /samples directory